# How to start using python on Linux Hosting

Tags: python, linux, server, cgi, web-hosting

I want to use python for my website.I have a Single Domain Linux hosting from BigRock. And I'hd SSH to my website to check if it has Python Installed so i did >>python -v  it turns out python 2.6.6 is already Installed. BigRock support Team asked me to put:

```
*Options +ExecCGI
**AddHandler cgi-script .py***
```

in .htaccess file.

But after Doing all this when i try to print Hello using hello.py file It returns 500 Internal Server error.What should I do?

Comment: Is the hello.py file in a directory with CGI privilege? Does it have execute permission? Does it have a valid shebang line? Note that Python 2.6.6 is rather old, and some common 2.7 features will raise an error, eg `s = '{}'.format('hello')` will raise `ValueError`.

Comment: yes, I have set permissions to 755

Comment: Is it _specifically_ a Python problem? Eg, can you run a simple Bash script from that directory?

Comment: Yes i did SSH to cgi-bin Directory Python seems to work fine 'myWeb@cp-in-8 [~/public_html/cgi-bin]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>'

Answer (score 2):

Adding Content Type Resolved The Problem.

For Those Who face Same Problem Here is The check List:

Make sure you have Python Installed:

> > You can SSH your website then type [ python -v ] on terminal it will show you which version of python is Installed.

Make sure you have following Code in .htaccess file. To view .htaccess file go to Legacy File manager Tick on show hidden dot files.

> > Add following code to it

```
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

> > Now place all your .py files in cgi-bin folder and set permission to 755
> >
> > Windows users do not forget to include python location on first line.
> >     And type of content on second line:

```
Location:/home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/test.py
```

Sample Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print "<html><head>";

print "<title>CGI Test</title>";

print "</head><body>";

print "<p>Test page using Python</p>";

print "</body></html>";
```

Comment: wow i didn't know we can run python on a simple shared hosting account!